# ReactJS How to display a constant function on success?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fairly new on reactjs and currently built a form that can submit to an API using Axiom with method POST.

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const isValid = formValidation()

        if (isValid) {
            console.log("Form Valid: Processing on Backend")

            // const data = new FormData(e.target);

            processBackend()
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            console.log("Form Invalid: Please check form")
        }
    }
```

My handleSubmit will call another function which is processBackend()

```
const processBackend = async () => {
        let res = await postUsers(mobileCountryCode, mobileNumber, firstName, lastName, organization)

        // console.log("postUsers.res:")
        // console.log(res)
        HandleResponse(res)

    }
```

Then I thought, I could display the functional app using the following code below to handle the response in either success or failed. But, it's not showing up.

```
const HandleResponse = (res) => {

        console.log("HandleResponse.res:")
        console.log(res)
        console.log(res.status)

        if (res.status === 200) {
            return <ResponseSuccess />
        } else if (res.status === 400 || res.status === 403 || res.status === 500) {
            return <ResponseError />
        } else {
            return false
        }

    }

    const ResponseSuccess = () => {
        return (
            <div className="notification">
                <button className="delete"></button>
                Successfully processed your request.
            </div>
        )
    }

    const ResponseError = () => {
        return (
            <div className="notification is-danger">
                <button className="delete"></button>
                There was an error processing your request.
            </div>
        )
    }
```

My render has the following

```
return (
        <div className="container">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

            <h1 className="title">Users</h1>
            <h2 className="subtitle">Create New User</h2>

            <HandleResponse />

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

The problem I think is right here

```
if (res.status === 200) {
                return <ResponseSuccess />
            } else if (res.status === 400 || res.status === 403 || res.status === 500) {
                return <ResponseError />
            } else {
                return false
            }
```

When I removed the return false and just return either success or failed, it's shows. But, on the actual res.status === 200 it's not showing up. On console log. I can see it's res.status = 200 actually.

What could be the best way to display either success or failed or to handle it properly?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: The op has written it as function and rendering it as component.It will not work.Just now noticed.

Comment: They are functional components not normal functions!

Comment: If `ResponseSuccess`, `ResponseError` and `HandleResponse` are functions that return JSX, how are they not functional components?

Comment: _The op has written it as function and rendering it as component.It will not work.Just now noticed_ - @HemaNandagopal - [It will work](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-wilbur-9lmqn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems in your code:

- You are not doing anything with the return value of `HandleResponse()` function
- `HandleResponse()` function is called **asynchronously**. React component or any other value that is returned from `HandleResponse()` function isn't returned to the place in your code where you called the function. Return value of an asynchronous function cannot be handled like you would handle synchronous function's return value.

**Solution:**

In case of a success response, you could save some value in the state that indicates that HTTP request compeleted successfully. Based on this state, you could render different components or display an error message.

In `handleResponse` function, depending on the status code, update the state of the component

```
const HandleResponse = (res) => {
    ...

    if (res.status === 200) {
       setState('success');
    } else {
       setState('error');
    }
}
```

then in the `JSX` code, render the appropriate component depending on the response as a result of the HTTP request.

```
return (
    ...
    { state == 'success' && <ResponseSuccess/> }
    { state == 'error' && <ResponseError/> }
);
```

Comment: This make sense a lot. I did read about https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html now and was able to set a const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState(""). One thing I could experience now, on page-load, it always shows <ResponseError/>

Comment: That's probably because you are rendering `ResponseError` component when `state == 'success'` is false. You need to render this component only when there's an error as a result of HTTP request.

Comment: Sorry, got it. Yes, by making state == 'success' and state == 'error' will resolve it on page load. Many thanks for your help! I am now more learning on reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

`HandleResponse` is expecting a parameter (`res`), but you're never passing it in. In your current code, there's no way for `HandleResponse` to know about `res`.

If you want to keep the if statements and the HandleResponse component unchanged, you could change it to take `res` as a prop:

```
const HandleResponse = ({res}) => /* rest of your code here */
```

You would then need to pass `res` as a prop when you use the component in your render:

```
<HandleResponse res={res} />
```

You'd need to change `processBackEnd` so that it updates the `res` variable somewhere in your application state, instead of calling `HandleResponse` directly.